# Issue with printing new line in Python

Tags: python

I want to print two variables in to two different lines. Want to understand the correct syntax for e.g.:

```
x=5,y=5
print (x,'\n',y) # leads to an error
```

Comment: What's the error? What version of Python?

Comment: Just `x=5,y=5` is an error...

Comment: the first line isn't valid syntax.  Try `x, y = 5, 5`

Answer (score -3, accepted):

assuming python3...

```
x=5
y=5
print(str(x) + '\n' + str(y))
```

EDIT:

this solution:

```
print(x,'\n',y)
```

will add an extra space before the y when you print it, so it will return:

```
5
 5
```

Comment: There is no point in converting to string here.

Comment: if you use "+" to build your string you do.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot write

```
x=5, y=5
print(x, '\n', y)
```

Try to write x and y on separate lines:

```
x=5
y=5 
print(x,'\n',y)
```

That should work

Comment: Or an f string: `f'{x}\n{y}'` or if debugging, especially helpful: `f'{x=}\n{y=}'` or use the `sep` option to print: `print(x,y,sep='\n')`